# Passing a String variable into a UIImage constructor does not return a UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this issue.

Currently in my Assets folder I have the following `decline bench.png` image:

[image]

In my code, I have a `String` variable `equipmentName` set somewhere else.

I set my `UIImageView` image like so:

```
equipmentImageView.image = UIImage(named: equipmentName)
```

However, the image is never returned.

I checked to see if the image can actually be returned:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: equipmentName)
{
    print("GOOD")
}
else
{
    print("BAD")
}
```

This prints out `BAD`.

However if I replaced `equipmentName` with the actual string name, it returns the correct image, and outputs `GOOD`:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "decline bench")
{
    print("GOOD")
}
else
{
    print("BAD")
}
```

What gives?

They are both the same thing, the type is a `String` so why does passing it the variable `equipmentName` of type `String` not work, but passing in a literal string work?

The variable `equipmentName` also contains the string `decline bench` before `equipmentImageView.image` is set.

Does it have anything to do with the naming of the image in the Assets folder?

Please help me understand. Thanks!

**MORE INFO**:
In my code, `equipmentName` is actually stored with upper-case first letters like so `Decline Bench`.

When I set the image, I am **actually** doing:

```
equipmentImageView.image = UIImage(named: equipmentName.lowercased())
```

`equipmentName.lowercased()` still returns a `String`, which does not work.

However, doing the following does work:

```
equipmentName = "decline bench"
equipmentImageView.image = UIImage(named: equipmentName)
```

What is the difference here that I am not doing correctly?

**UPDATE:** The following print out produces:

`print(Data(equipmentName.utf8) as NSData)`: **<4465636c 696e6520 42656e63 680a2020 20202020 20202020 2020>**

`print(Data(equipmentName.lowercased().utf8) as NSData)`: **<6465636c 696e6520 62656e63 680a2020 20202020 20202020 2020>**

Comment: add 1x and 3x images to solve this issue

Comment: Could you check if `equipmentName == "decline bench"`?

Comment: where you have your `equipmentName = "decline bench"` ??

Comment: `print(">\(equipmentName)<")` directly before the image is loaded, and show us the result.

Comment: Updated more info

Comment: Could you check that `equipmentName.lowercased() == "decline bench"` then? Until you can't prove that the var you put in param of `UIImage(named:)` isn't `"decline bench"`, you won't go anywhere. Try to understand why it's different first.

Comment: @Pangu Use `equipmentName = "decline bench.png" ` instead of `equipmentName = "decline bench" `. I not sure but may this will work.

Comment: I don't see why this should not work, perhaps there is some (hidden) space or control character in the string. – **Please show**  us the output of `print(Data(equipmentName.utf8) as NSData)`

Comment: Is your `equipmentName` comes form Server like form as webservice response ? , There may be hidden characters are there ,

Comment: @Larme, you are correct, `equipmentName.lowercased() != "decline bench"`...but I don't understand why....printing out `equipmentName.lowercased()` shows `decline bench`...what is the difference here?

Comment: Just check one condition  equipmentName == "decline bench" to verify

Comment: Is there an extra space somewhere? A hidden character? A possibility should be to convert it to NSData and check the data.

Comment: Your output `... 0a2020 20202020 20202020 2020` shows that `equipmentName` has a newline character and several space characters at the end ...

Comment: @MartinR thank you!...that was the issue, I will look into this

Comment: @Pangu: I am glad that your problem is solved. However, this Q&A is not likely to help any future reader (you claimed that the string variable is equal to the literal string, but it isn't). Passing a string variable into the UIImage constructor *does work as expected.* – My suggestion would be just to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

You said `equipmentName = "Decline Bench"`, It's wrong, your asset named `decline bench` without the uppercase, just change it to lowercase then it work.

It have to have the correct case, `D` and `d` are different character

Comment: Are you aware that OP calls `UIImage(named: equipmentName.lowercased())` ?

Comment: Then can you just print your `equipmentName` out then tell us? If not then just copy paste your working string to `equipmentName`

Answer (score 0):

Credits to **@Martin R** and **@Larme**:

The issue was that `equipmentName` contained newline characters as well as spacing, causing `UIImage(named: equipmentName.lowercased())` to not recognized the passed in `String` parameter `equipmentName.lowercased()`.

Eliminating the extra spacing in `equipmentName` before setting the `imageView.image` resolved the issue.